# What's the correct parameter to use on tf.keras.models.load_model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm new using Pyhton and I'm kinda lost trying setup keras save model and weights, someone with more experience could help me please?

I'm folloing this guide to learn how predict system works and would give advices in lottery games:

https://medium.com/@polanitzer/predicting-the-israeli-lottery-results-for-the-november-29-2022-game-using-an-artificial-191489eb2c10

On my Jurassic computer this is frozing in random epochs above 900, then reading tensorflow docs have see about possibility to use save weights on every epoch and continue from previous one if it fails / computer frozen.

I have did to checkpoint:

```
    checkpoint_filepath="/home/ubuntu/Downloads/Lottery/checkpoints/lottery/"
model_checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=os.path.join(checkpoint_filepath,"weights-improvement.hd5"),
    monitor='val_accuracy',
    verbose=1,
    save_best_only=True,
    save_weights_only=True,
    save_freq='epoch',
    mode='max')
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', patience=5)
callbacks_list = [model_checkpoint_callback, es]
```

And to load model:

```
model.load_weights("/home/ubuntu/Downloads/Lottery/checkpoints/lottery/weights-improvement.hd5")
loss, acc = model.evaluate(train_samples, train_labels, verbose=2)
print("Restored model, accuracy: {:5.2f}%".format(100 * acc))
load_model('/home/ubuntu/Downloads/Lottery/lottery/')
```

Tried use train_samples / train_labels and x_train / y_train, no luck restoring then, runing all code in jupyter notebook, this start from begin everytime (0.08% accuracy even previous run have get 60% before frozen).

And at training model I have did:

```
model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=1200, verbose=2, callbacks=[model_checkpoint_callback], validation_split=0.22)

model.save('lottery')
```

I was reading docs from here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advice to all able to try help me!!!

Comment: just give the directory path to save and load files, not a file with `.h5` extension.

Comment: You point me in right direction, I used path to save like you sayed and added save_format='tf'

Now its working, make an answer for I vote as solution, tyvm

Comment: This is hugging face? Did you use trainer.save_model or model.save_pretrained?

Comment: Hey @V.M, the hangups are because its runing on old and crap computer, when RAM get 100% (8GB only) usage after some random time crash, I have SWAP partition but seems don't work. to save I'm using 2 solutions like in description on main post: 1- Checkpoint on callback on every epoch 2 - mode.save if finish all 1200 epochs. Problem was on load, but now its working, I will add an answer with the changes, and please make your advice as answer too because using your hint I have found another post about force tf format instead .h5 and everything its working now.

Comment: Initially I didn't have any completed training (so the load part I left commented), only the checkpoints, changing to TF format and using your directory hint, even with the crashes, I managed to complete more than the 1200 epochs to have an better accuracy  and now I have both to load in the future (checkpoint and model.save).